# Xcode JSON how to get value from an array

Tags: json, xcode

I implemented this to get an array from LastFm.

```
NSError *error;
NSString *url_string = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getInfo&api_key=47c35d956f7cd6b43ab94586f0fd3a&artist=Blondie&track=Heart+of+Glass&format=json"]; 
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:url_string]];
NSMutableArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSLog(@"json: %@", json);
```

and this part is working fine I'm getting this data:

```
track =     {
    album =         {
        "@attr" =             {
            position = 1;
        };
        artist = Blondie;
        image =             (
                            {
                "#text" = "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/ee5b3f50b00a4678c6de7b908c505fb4.png";
                size = small;
            },


                            {
                "#text" = "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/ee5b3f50b00a4678c6de7b908c505fb4.png";
                size = medium;
            },
                            {
                "#text" = "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/ee5b3f50b00a4678c6de7b908c505fb4.png";
                size = large;
            },
                            {
                "#text" = "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/ee5b3f50b00a4678c6de7b908c505fb4.png";
                size = extralarge;
            }
        );
```

My question is how can I get value from this key "#text"

"#text" = "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/ee5b3f50b00a4678c6de7b908c505fb4.png";
                    size = large;

something like:

NSLog(@"Large Image: %@", "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/ee5b3f50b00a4678c6de7b908c505fb4.png");

I literally tried everything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying you want to download the image?

Comment: No, I just want to get the info (path) of the image into variable, I need the value from the key "#text".

Comment: I figure this one out (finally LOL) , Thanks